# Jailkit: cannot su to jailed user

Tags: ubuntu, chroot, jail, jailkit

As a part of a bigger setup (docker container with safe environment for running python scripts), I need to configure a jailed user. I have looked at different options and decided to try [Jailkit](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/). Unfortunately, I have a problem with trying to setup a jail for user - basically, a jail does not work for me at all. The steps I have done are:

```
#install jailkit
apt-get install -y wget make python2.7 gcc
wget http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/jailkit-2.19.tar.gz
tar -xzvf jailkit-2.19.tar.gz
cd jailkit-2.19
./configure; make;
sudo checkinstall

# create new user
sudo adduser --disabled-password --gecos Python python

# create a jail for this user
sudo mkdir /home/tjail
sudo jk_init -v -j /home/tjail jk_lsh
sudo jk_init -v -j /home/tjail basicshell
sudo jk_jailuser -m -j /home/tjail python
```

Now I expected to try to login as this user:

```
sudo su - python
```

However, nothing happens after I execute this command, I'm not getting switched to the jailed user. Do you know, what could be wrong?

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, but also have the same issue on 14.04...

**UPDATE:** /etc/password looks good:

```
python:x:1001:1001:Python,,,:/home/tjail/./home/python:/usr/sbin/jk_chrootsh
```

**UPDATE 2:** I have also tried changing /usr/sbin/jk_chrootsh to /bin/bash. Now I can su to this user, but then the jail seems not to be working. E.g., I can go to the real system root, browse real home, see settings in the /etc or read /etc/passwd file (normal one)...

Comment: can you check this users login shell? I assume it is set to something like `/sbin/nologin`. Try running this: `cat /etc/passwd | grep python`, you may need to change the shell using `usermod -s /bin/bash python`

Comment: Are you sure the /bin/bash is needed there? Cause from the documentation I have read, jk_chrootsh should be fine (http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/howtos_chroot_shell.html). Also, my final goal is having as minimal environment as possible. Actually, the docker container will be started, then 1 python script should be executed, and container destroyed after it. Shouldn't it work without bash?

Comment: Hey, sorry - I posted another comment jhust as SE had some downtime before, looks like it didnt go through. It looks like your users home directory is `/home/tjail/./home/python`, is this correct?? Or should it just be `/home/python`?

Comment: '/home/tjail/./home/python' should be correct, since jailkit copies /home/python to /home/tjail. I have also tried changing /usr/sbin/jk_chrootsh to /bin/bash. Now I can su to this user, but then the jail seems not to be working. E.g., I can go to the real system root, browse real home, see setting in the etc or read /etc/passwd file (normal one)...

Comment: try   `sudo strace su - python`    and also check dmesg and other logs (eg. /var/log/secure or /var/log/auth.log)